# Piece of code on a python project won't run as intended

Tags: python

There's a small section in my python school project that isn't running as i intend:

```
elif "eat berry" in command:
    if inventory == 'berry':
        typingPrint("You eat a berry")
        Penguin.health = Penguin.health + 10
        print("Your health is now", Penguin.health)
        userInput()
    else:
        typingPrint("sorry you can't eat that right now.")
        userInput()
```

when i run this code even if i have a berry in the inventory (the inventory is created as a list), it still prints "Sorry you can't eat that right now." Any idea on how to fix this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the `inventory` _literally equal_ to the string `'berry'`, or is `inventory` supposed to _contain_ this string? `inventory == 'berry'` checks for _equality_.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `in` operator, since `["berry"] != "berry"`

```
if "berry" in inventory:
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your inventory is a list, then you need to change this
`if inventory == 'berry':` into
`if 'berry' in inventory :`

Answer (score 0):

If inventory is of type `list`, then you should check that the item in question, `"berry"`, is in the list `inventory`:

```py
if "berry" in inventory:
    # do something
```